# Get request_ids in a canvas app

Tags: facebook, canvas

I have a facebook canvas app like this: http://dpaste.com/809111/

I use this to redirect user on my site when a user invite friends on my site with facebook multi friends selector.

When a user receive the request on facebook, he clicks on a link like this:

http://apps.facebook.com/XXXXX/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=XXXXXX&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user

and then, through my facebook canvas app will be redirect on my site.

Ok, perfect.

Now, i would want to catch request_ids and redirect the user on a custom link, like this:

mysite.com/invite/?request_ids=XXXXXX

to track invite and result from invite.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `$_GET[request_ids]`, easy :)

Comment: This is no longer possible - is there a way around?